# How to parse a JSON in Kotlin (Anko)?

Tags: android, json, kotlin, deserialization, anko

I have used [Anko](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko) to get a JSON in Kotlin and it works well but I do not know how can I access to each value.

I have this code which prints out the whole JSON:

```
doAsync {
  val result = URL("url.json").readText()
     uiThread {
     longToast(result)
  }
}
```

So now that I have the whole JSON, how can I access to each field?

I have tried with `result[0].toString()`and `result.get(0).toString()` but it did not work because it prints out the first character of `result` which is `[`

Comment: Did you try using Gson Library? It can parse your Json response to your Model Object. Like.
`val responseObj = Gson.fromJson<yourModelClass>(response, yourModelClass::class.java`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `JSONArray` and `JSONObject` to parse json like below.

In **Java**:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
for (int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    String user = jsonObject.getString("user");
    String password = jsonObject.getString("password");
}
```

In **Kotlin**:

```
val jsonArray = JSONArray(result)
for (i in 0 until jsonArray.length()) {
    val jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)
    val user = jsonObject.getString("user")
    val password = jsonObject.getString("password")
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this has worked and without using libraries, perfect!

Comment: Welcome @AdriánT95. Glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a cool kotlinx library called [Kotlinx.Serialization](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization)

In **root** `build.gradle`

```
buildScript {
    ...
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-serialization:$kotlin_version"
}
```

The use the `@Serializable` annotation ( for your custom class )

For **deserialization** use :-

```
 Json.parse(YourClass.serializer() ,resultJson) // this will deserialize
```

For **serialization** use :-

```
 Json.stringify(YourClass.serializer(), yourClassObj) // this will give string value of the json
```

> For more info check [this](https://ahsensaeed.com/kotlinx-serialization-library-android-kotlin/).